# Need to export and import certificates from windows server using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a UCCE environment where there are 8 Windows servers and 4 CUCM servers(Linux) installed on it.
I need to export all the certificates from all the 8 Windows servers and 4 CUCM servers.

Code:

```
dir cert:\localmachine\my | Where-Object { $_.hasPrivateKey } |   Foreach-Object { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\$($_.Subject).cer",     ($_.Export('CER', 'secret')) ) }
```

I wasn't able to export a certificate from remote Windows servers, I tried below code:

```
$Srv = "remoteserver.com"
$Certs = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -Computername $Srv -Scriptblock {Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_.` to access the current object in the where-object and foreach-object cmdlet.

Powershell has also a [pkiclient module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps) where you can use the `export-certificate` cmdlet

Comment: i can able to access and download the local windows machine certificate but i need to download remote windows server certificate from same cert:/ path